# How can send query with masking regex in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table `Person`. The table has name and age columns. I need a query that will dynamically change columns with replace pattern.

For example:

```
select * 
from person [whatever] REPLACE(name, 'a', 'XXXXX')
```

I expected result like this:

```
XXXXlex     martinez
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: select REPLACE(name,'a', 'XXXXX'),age from employees. I cant do that. They have to split.

Comment: The query  have not  to  ``select * from person``. It is can be `` select name, age from person``

Comment: What do you mean "dynamically change column with replace pattern" as it's it's value? `REPLACE` replaces 1 character string with another. So `REPLACE('A character string','a', 'XXXXX')` would return `'XXXXX chXXXXXrXXXXXcter string'`. It would be terrible for data masking.

Comment: you want to replace with x first 4 digit..

Comment: @Larnu Yes, but pattern doesn't matter. I wonder İs there a function  for me.

Comment: Suppose the query like that  ``select name, age from person `` I want to transform it like `` select REPLACE(name,'a', 'XXXXX'), age from person``

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the first four characters to `'X'`, use `STUFF()`:

```
select stuff(name, 1, 4, 'XXXX')
```

If you want a "name" that is hidden, the use a view:

```
create view v_person as
    select stuff(name, 1, 4, 'XXXX') as name, age
    from person;
```

Users who use the view will only see the modified name.

Comment: I want to change column "name" to REPLACE(name, 'a', 'XXXXX'). But user will send query like ``select name from employee and REPLACE(name, 'a', 'XXXXX')``

Comment: That isn't how SQL works, @bilinmeyenkarakter . You can't replace part of the query itself with a different expression; if you want to use that expression you need to define it in your SQL statement. You can't pass `name` and expect it to be replaced with `REPLACE(name, 'a', 'XXXXX')`. Gordon's second suggestion, using a `VIEW` therefore seems like a good candidate here.

Comment: Also, like i said above, @bilinmeyenkarakter, `REPLACE(name, 'a', 'XXXXX')` is an awful masking process. For Gordon's name here, for example, their name would *still* be `'Gordon Linoff'` even after applying your "masking".

Comment: @Gordon, I believe you want `stuff(name, 1, 4, 'XXXX')`. `STUFF` would only replace the characters with a single `X` here, not 4.

Comment: @Larnu the pattern for easy to see. I am hashing in real. So Is there a way to like forbidden columns? When user write ``select name from person`` Its will forbidden or ``select name,age from person`` in this query answer will only age ?

Comment: Again, sounds like you want a `VIEW` then, @bilinmeyenkarakter .